# All Goals trigger through programmatically are visible in Experience Profile but not in Experience Analytics report

Tags: xconnect, reporting, fxm

All `Goals` trigger through programmatically are visible in the `Experience Profile` > `Goal` Report but not in `Experience Analytics` Report.
We have triggered goal programmatically and attached with a `Contact`. these Goals are visible in `Experience Profile` but not in `Experience Analytics`.

Need your inputs.

```
Contact gExistingContact = client.Get<Contact>(new IdentifiedContactReference(_identifier, userKey),
                           new ContactExpandOptions(PersonalInformation.DefaultFacetKey));

                    if (gExistingContact != null)
                    {
                        Guid glID = Guid.Parse(goalId.ToString());
                        var goalItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(goalId);

                        var xconnectEvent = new Goal(glID, DateTime.UtcNow);

                        xconnectEvent.CustomValues.Add("Action", action);
                        xconnectEvent.CustomValues.Add("PageName", pageName);
                        xconnectEvent.CustomValues.Add("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString());

                        if (goalItem != null)
                        {
                            if (goalItem["Points"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(goalItem["Points"].ToString()))
                            {
                                xconnectEvent.EngagementValue = goalItem["Points"] == null ? 0 : int.Parse(goalItem["Points"].ToString());
                            }
                        }

                        Guid channelId = Guid.Parse(channelid.ToString());
                        var useragent = "Mozilla / 5.0(iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit / 602.1.50(KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS / 56.0.2924.75 Mobile / 14E5239e Safari/ 602.1";
                        Interaction interaction = new Sitecore.XConnect.Interaction(gExistingContact, InteractionInitiator.Contact, channelId, useragent);
                        interaction.Events.Add(xconnectEvent);
                        client.AddInteraction(interaction);
                        client.Submit();
                    }
```

Comment: You issue is that your interaction is not a page/web interaction. It is an xConnect interaction. And by default Sitecore does not include non-web based interactions into Experience Analytics. In Himmat Singh Dulawat answer below, that is a web interaction `Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.RegisterGoal`. You can change you goal to a web interaction or let me find you the setting to include the non-web interaction in EA.

Answer (score 3):

If your interaction doesn`t have WebVisit it is invisible in Experience Analytics by default. You can change you goal to a web interaction as @Chris Auer mentioned or remove(patch)

```
<InteractionFilter type="Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Filters.WebVisitFilter, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation" />
```

from **Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.config** for corresponding dimensions to make interactions without WebVisit visible in EA.

If you need web visit for your interaction but you don`t have *Tracker.Current* in your API context you can modify your code to add "fake" web visit:

```
//Add Device profile
DeviceProfile newDeviceProfile = new DeviceProfile(Guid.NewGuid()) { LastKnownContact = gExistingContact };
client.AddDeviceProfile(newDeviceProfile);
interaction.DeviceProfile = newDeviceProfile;

//Add fake Ip info
IpInfo fakeIpInfo = new IpInfo("127.0.0.1") { BusinessName = "Home"};
client.SetFacet(interaction, IpInfo.DefaultFacetKey, fakeIpInfo);

// Add fake webvisit
// Create a new web visit facet model
var webVisitFacet = new WebVisit
{
    Browser =
        new BrowserData
        {
            BrowserMajorName = "Chrome",
            BrowserMinorName = "Desktop",
            BrowserVersion = "22.0"
        },
    Language = "en",
    OperatingSystem =
        new OperatingSystemData { Name = "Windows", MajorVersion = "10", MinorVersion = "4" },
    Referrer = "https://www.google.com",
    Screen = new ScreenData { ScreenHeight = 1080, ScreenWidth = 685 },
    SearchKeywords = "sitecore",
    SiteName = "website"
};

// Populate data about the web visit
// Home page itemId
var itemId = Guid.Parse("110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9");
var itemVersion = 1;

// First page view
PageViewEvent pageView = new PageViewEvent(DateTime.Now,
    itemId, itemVersion, "en")
{
    ItemLanguage = "en",
    Duration = new TimeSpan(3000),
    Url = "/home"
};

interaction.Events.Add(pageView);
client.SetWebVisit(interaction, webVisitFacet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code as below, it works for me and I am able to see Goal in Experience Profile and in Experience Analytics Report as well.

```
if (!Tracker.IsActive)
        {
            Tracker.StartTracking();
        }
        if (Tracker.IsActive && Tracker.Current.CurrentPage != null)
        {
            Sitecore.Data.Items.Item goalItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(goalId);
            if (goalItem != null)
            {
                var goalTrigger = Tracker.MarketingDefinitions.Goals[goalId.ToGuid()];
                var goalEventData = Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.RegisterGoal(goalTrigger);
                goalEventData.Data = goalItem["Name"];
                goalEventData.ItemId = goalItem.ID.ToGuid();
                goalEventData.DataKey = goalItem.Paths.Path;
                goalEventData.Text = goalItem["Name"];
                Tracker.Current.Interaction.AcceptModifications();
            }
        }
```

Here `goalId` is `Guid Type` of created goal in the marketing control panel. You can find more details about How to create a goal and deploy [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/create-and-deploy-a-goal.html).

Comment: I am triggering the **Goal**  through external API. We are using **FXM**  in our project. In that case the above code will work?